# Sqlalchemy does not work with pagination

Tags: postgresql, pagination, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am totally new with flask and sqlalchemy. I try to make one web site just to get better understanding of flask. There are plenty of tutorials and they are mostly use sqlite. For my purpose I use postgres. and I need one page where I can use pagination. But all the time I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'paginate'
```

my database

```
uri = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'postgres://login:password@127.0.0.1/db_name')
engine = create_engine(uri, convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                     autoflush=False,
                     bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

simple model

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(100), nullable=False)
    ...
```

then I use paginate

```
users = User.query.paginate(1, 5, False)
```

The same error with get_or_404() and first_or_404(). normal get or first works as usual.

I will appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `paginate()` on a query object provided by SQLAlchemy, but the pagination functionality is only available from a  Flask-SQLAlchemy, which subclasses the base query object to add this and other features, including the `get_or_404()` and `first_or_404()` methods that you also found to not work.

All this happens because you created your database and your model using SQLAlchemy directly instead of using the facilities provided by Flask-SQLAlchemy. If you do this according to the Flask-[SQLAlchemy documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) you will find that everything will work just fine.

Comment: am also facing the same problem, so i need to create my models using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` instead of sqlalchemy?? to achieve pagination

Comment: How do I get the pagination to work with just SQLAlchemy? Please help.

Comment: @Hussain: you can use the `limit()` and `offset()` query modifiers to request a subset of the results.

Comment: Looks like Flask-Alchemy uses limit and offset as well. https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/main/src/flask_sqlalchemy/pagination.py#L358C15-L358C74

Answer (score 0):

use **limit()** and **offset()** for pagination using mysql sqlalchemy.

```
query = User.query.limit().offset()
data = query.all()
```

you'll get the desired results.

Comment: Please add information on parameters for `limit()` and `offset()` and that this is only necessary if you use base SQLAlchemy and not Flask-SQLAlchemy.