# Flask-SQLAlchemy Query Join relational tables

Tags: join, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building an app using Flask & SQLAlchemy. I basically have 3 tables: users, friendships and bestFriends:

A user can have many friends but only one best friend. So I want my model to be relational. 'One-to-many' for the relation between 'users' and 'friendships' & 'one-to-one' between 'users' and 'bestFriends'.

This is my Model:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class users(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userEmail = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPhone = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPass = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    friendsR = db.relationship('friendships', backref='friendships.friend_id', primaryjoin='users.id==friendships.user_id', lazy='joined')

    def __init__(self, userName, userEmail, userPhone, userPass):
        self.userName = userName
        self.userEmail = userEmail
        self.userPhone = userPhone
        self.userPass = userPass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.id, self.userName, self.userEmail, self.userPhone)

class friendships(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Friendships"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    userR = relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.user_id')
    friendR = relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, friend_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.friend_id = friend_id


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.friend_id)


class bestFriends(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "BestFriends"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    best_friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    user = relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.user_id')
    best_friend = relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.best_friend_id')


    def __init__(self, user_id, best_friend_id):

        self.user_id = user_id
        self.best_friend_id = best_friend_id


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.best_friend_id)
```

I need to be able to query the list of friends of the user logged in as well as the best friend of that user in case exists. I also need to PAGINATE the result:

Here is my app.py function for displaying the friends of a user:

```
@app.route('/friendList<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/friends')
def friendList(page=1):

if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        userID = session['user_id']

        userList = users.query.join(friendships).add_columns(users.id, users.userName, users.userEmail, friendships.user_id, friendships.friend_id).filter(users.id == friendships.friend_id).filter(friendships.user_id == userID).paginate(page, 1, False)

        return render_template(
            'friends.html', userList=userList)
```

And this would be the Jinja side of the code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<div id="pagination">
{% if userList.has_prev %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('friendList', page=userList.prev_num) }}">Back</a>
{% endif %} 

{% if userList.has_next %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('friendList', page=userList.next_num) }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="innerContent">
{% if userList %}
    {% for friends in userList %}
                    <div class="contentUsers">
                        {{ friends.userName }}
                    </div>

                    <br><br><br><br>

    {% endfor %}{% else %}<div>No friends</div>
{% endif %} 

</div>
  {% endblock %}
```

And if I query like this:

```
userList = db.session.query(users,friendships).filter(users.id == friendships.friend_id).filter(friendships.user_id == userID).paginate(page, 1, False)
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from. Tried joining to <class 'models.friendships'>, but got: Can't determine join between 'Users' and 'Friendships'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

If I query like this:

```
userList = users.query.join(friendships, users.id==friendships.user_id).add_columns(users.id, users.userName, users.userEmail, friendships.user_id, friendships.friend_id).filter(users.id == friendships.friend_id).filter(friendships.user_id == userID).paginate(page, 1, False)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable
```

I still think this later query is right way to go but I think there is something wrong in my relationships/foreign keys between tables!!!

If on the Jinja side I add the .items to the loop:

```
{% if userList.items %}
{% for friends in userList.items %}

                <div class="contentUsers">
                    {{ friends.userName }}
                </div>

                <br><br><br><br>

{% endfor %}{% else %}<div>No friends</div>
```

{% endif %}

It doesn't loop at all and simply displays the else statement of "no friends"

Comment: See these questions which may steer you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468887/flask-sqlalchemy-pagination-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409645/sqlalchemy-does-not-work-with-pagination

Comment: Hello Matthewh and thank you for your comment. Now I realize why I was able to apply the paginate() to some of my query and others not. But I still dont know how to perform the join query I need with Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have simple query working with paginate like: "userList = users.query.paginate(page, 5, False)" But I don't know how to perform a Flask-SQLAlchemy version(with paginate) of for example:"SELECT users.userId, users.name, users.email, friends.userId, friendId
FROM users
INNER JOIN friends
ON users.userId=friends.friendId
WHERE friends.userId=1"...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The error message is telling you that SQLAlchemy can't determine how to join the two tables `users` and `friendships`, because there is more than one foreign key linking them. You need to explicitly define the join condition.

Try:

```
userList = users.query\
    .join(friendships, users.id==friendships.user_id)\
    .add_columns(users.userId, users.name, users.email, friends.userId, friendId)\
    .filter(users.id == friendships.friend_id)\
    .filter(friendships.user_id == userID)\
    .paginate(page, 1, False)
```

Comment: Sorry Matthewh, was very tired, did not realize the column names I was using  where the ones from my MySql example not my SqlAlchemy model: this would be the correct collumn names for the query you wrote me(still gives me error I added to original question):                                                          userList = users.query.join(friendships, users.id==friendships.user_id).add_columns(users.id, users.userName, users.userEmail, friendships.user_id, friendships.friend_id).filter(users.id == friendships.friend_id).filter(friendships.user_id == userID).paginate(page, 1, False)

Comment: Can you explain what the `.add_columns()` does? Is that necessary after joining?

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like after getting some sleep and viewing Matthewh's suggestion I almost found the  final solution:

My model:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userEmail = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPhone = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPass = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, userName, userEmail, userPhone, userPass):
        self.userName = userName
        self.userEmail = userEmail
        self.userPhone = userPhone
        self.userPass = userPass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.id, self.userName, self.userEmail, self.userPhone)


 class friendships(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Friendships"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    userR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.user_id')
    friendR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, friend_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.friend_id = friend_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.friend_id)


class bestFriends(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "BestFriends"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    best_friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.user_id')
    best_friend = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.best_friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, best_friend_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.best_friend_id = best_friend_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.best_friend_id)
```

My app.py function(shows friends of user logged in):

```
@app.route('/friendList<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/friends')
  def friendList(page=1):
  if not session.get('logged_in'):
     return render_template('login.html')
  else:
     userID = session['user_id']
     userList = users.query.join(friendships, users.id==friendships.user_id).add_columns(users.id, users.userName, users.userEmail, friendships.id, friendships.user_id, friendships.friend_id).filter(friendships.friend_id == userID).paginate(page, 1, False)
     return render_template('friends.html', userList=userList)
```

And the Jinja side of 'friends.html':

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="pagination">
        {% if userList.has_prev %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('friendList', page=userList.prev_num)}}">Back</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if userList.has_next %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('friendList', page=userList.next_num)}}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div id="innerContent">
    {% if userList.items %}
        {% for friends in userList.items %}
            <div class="contentUsers">
                {{ friends.userName }}
            </div>
            <br><br><br><br>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div>No friends</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This gives me an object(friends in userList.items) like this:

```
(2-Carlos-carlos@carlos.com-900102030, 2, u'Carlos', u'carlos@carlos.com', 2, 2, 1)
```

I was expecting this:
    |users.id|users.userName|users.userEmail|users.userPhone|friendships.id|friendships.user_id(the friends)| friendships.friend_id(the logged in user)|

So I have the following doubts/questions:

I am not completely understanding the structure of the object resulting for the query:

-repeated user id, name and email
-what is the 'u' infront of second name and email

I am not completely understanding the relations model structure:

- why is the following NOT required in the 'users' class of the database model:

  ```
  #friendsR = db.relationship('friendships', backref='friendships.friend_id', primaryjoin='users.id==friendships.user_id', lazy='joined')
  ```

**IS my database model correctly defined regarding standarized relationship model as posted in this answer or should I improove some how??**

Comment: Why don't you define only two models (users & friendships) and add a boolean entry for a "is best friend" friendship? That would simplify your queries by a lot. If you wanna find a user's bestfriend you just have to add a filter by "is best friend equals true".