# Use Flask-SqlAlchemy to query relationship database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Flask-SQLAlchemy to query out database for the user profile page

So far I don't have a solution for this problem, only able to query all the User data by using `users.query.all()`

Each user has their own role_id, department_id, researchfield_id.

How can i query out all the Role, Department, ResearchField data that has relationship with User through ID?

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    research_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('researchfields.id'))

class Department(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "departments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(100), unique=True)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='department',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Role(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(100), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role',
                                lazy='dynamic')


class ResearchField(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "researchfields"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("researchfields.id") , nullable=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='researchfield', lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900018/flask-sqlalchemy-query-join-relational-tables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're seeking for is a way to filter out users based on a specific model. Because in your example, the other way around is redundant - every user has only one department, so no need to filter out departments for that user. In order to achieve that, I would use the `backref` method provided by `SQLAlchemy` from the `User` model.

Here's an example consisting of two of the models:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'))
    department = db.relationship("Department", backref=backref("users", lazy="dynamic"))

class Department(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "departments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(100), unique=True)
```

Now you can use:

```py
department = Department.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
print(department.users.filter_by(is_admin=True).all()) # get all admins with that department
```

Every user has only one department, so you could just get the user's department by:

```py
user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
print(user.department) # prints Department object
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser!.

Comment: I need to display data model as a treeview. Can you suggest me how to do it? Thanks alot!!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that. You should open a new question with the code that you've tried and I'm sure you'll get your answer!

Comment: Nice. I am trying to do something similar: Apply filter only if variables are defined.... Filter conditionally, using the same sub-query. It's been proving to be quite a challenge... I'm using a List approach, with `filter_conditions = []` being added when conditions met, and at the end I pass them all using `query = query.filter(*filter_conditions)`.