# trying to get a set of data across multiple tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to put together two tables to get the data I need with flask-sqlalchemy.  The Venue table contains the venue's city and state and the Show table keeps track of the shows for each venue.  I need the query to group the Venues by city and state and then within that count the number of shows where start_time is greater than now.  So far all I have is this:

```
query = db.session.query(Venue.city, Venue.state, Venue.name, Venue.id, Show.venue_id, Show.start_time).group_by(Venue.city)
```

but I don't know where to go from there or even if that is the correct starting point.  These are my models:

```
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venue'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_talent = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String())
    genres = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String))
    website = db.Column(db.String())
    pastshows = db.relationship('Show', backref='pastshows', lazy=True)

class Show(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'show'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venue.id'), nullable=False)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'), nullable=False)
    artist_name = db.Column(db.String())
    venue_name = db.Column(db.String())
    venue_image = db.Column(db.String())
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
```

and this is the data I need:

```
data=[{
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "venues": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "The Musical Hop",
      "num_upcoming_shows": 0,
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Park Square Live Music & Coffee",
      "num_upcoming_shows": 1,
    }]
  }, {
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "venues": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "The Dueling Pianos Bar",
      "num_upcoming_shows": 0,
    }]
  }]
```

Can someone help me with this query?

Comment: What is the output of the query you currently have?
query = db.session.query(Venue.city, Venue.state, Venue.name, Venue.id, Show.venue_id, Show.start_time).group_by(Venue.city)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915077/5015356), which performs a [SQL JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/tutorial-join.html) between the two tables - if you don't, you'll get what's called a Cartesian product. If you have a list `['a', 'b']` and `[1, 2, 3]`, then the Cartesian product is `['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']`, and you can probably see that this will get out of hand soon.

Anyway, the code you're looking for looks similar to what you have

```py
query = db.session.query(
    Venue.city,
    Venue.state,
    Venue.name,
    Venue.id,
    Show.venue_id,
    Show.start_time
).select_from(Venue).join(
    Show, Show.venue_id = Venue.id
).group_by(Venue.city)
```

There are a few things, that I wrote as explicitly as possible, but that can actually be simplified, though:

1. `.select_from` tells you the FROM clause, but if omitted, the table of the very first argument to `.query()` is taken - so `Venue` is already the default here.
2. You've declared `pastshows` as a [relationship](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/?highlight=relationship#one-to-many-relationships), so that means Flask-SQLAlchemy should know how to link the two tables. In that case, you don't have to specify that it's the ID of the venue that matches the `venue_id`, and the code becomes `.join(Show)` instead, it makes the explicit implicit.

Thus, the following should also work, but it handles more things implicitly and thus has a higher degree of magic. I wanted to add it for completeness.

```py
query = db.session.query(
    Venue.city,
    Venue.state,
    Venue.name,
    Venue.id,
    Show.venue_id,
    Show.start_time
).join(Show).group_by(Venue.city)
```